Create a Task Sheet By CTE
In SQL Server I have a table named task with columns:



task_id
task_name
task_weight
task_parent




1,
t1
null
null


2
t2
null
1


3
t3
0.03
1


4
t4
0.04
2


5
t5
0.03
2


6
t6
null
null


7
t7
0.01
6



The task_parent column is a foreign key which may be null or be related to another task_id in this table.
I want to write a CTE to show tasks in a sheet like MS Project where task_weight of atask row with some recursive children, is summarized from its children and level of each child is calculated based on its recursive parents. Each child may have another child and so on. So consider this to calculate top level weight.
the schema is like this:
CREATE TABLE TASK
(
    task_id     int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    task_name   varchar(100),
    task_weight float,
    task_parent int
);

And the data is like this:
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [task] ON;
INSERT INTO task (task_id,task_name,task_weight,task_parent) VALUES
(1,'t1',null,null),
(2,'t2',null,1),
(3,'t3',0.03,1),
(4,'t4',0.04,2),
(5,'t5',0.03,2),
(6,'t6',null,null),
(7,'t7',0.01,6);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [task] OFF;

I expect a result like this (consider the order please):



task_name
task_weight
Level




t1
0.10
1


__t2
0.07
2


____t4
0.04
3


____t5
0.03
3


__t3
0.03
2


t6
0.01
1


__t7
0.01
2




There are a lot of examples of how to use a rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression). What about those examples didn't you understand? What did you try? Why didn't it work?

@ThomA Could you link to an example of how to use a recursive CTE that solves this problem? I'll reformulate the example into an answer to this question.

Does this answer your question? SQL Server CTE and recursion example

Does this answer your question? SQL Server CTE and recursion example

Use decimal(3, 2) rather than float.

I think it's safe to say the linked stackoverflow question is completely unrelated, not applicable in any way, and does not help answer this question at all. shawnt00's answer is ingenius, and uses a novel chain-parsing algorithm.

Mostly this is just a standard recursive query. To accumulate the weight this query creates a chain of task names that describes that position in the tree. That chain is then a useful prefix to identify all the node children and to find the sum with a cross apply (which could just as well be a regular scalar subquery):
with r as (
    select 1 as level, task_id, task_name,
        cast(task_weight as decimal(3, 2)) as task_weight,
        cast(concat(task_name, '>') as varchar(max)) as task_chain
    from task
    where task_parent is null
    union all
    select level + 1, t.task_id, t.task_name,
        t.task_weight, concat(r.task_chain, t.task_name, '>')
    from task t inner join r on r.task_id = t.task_parent
)
select
    concat(replicate('__', level - 1), r.task_name) as task_name,
    cumulative_weight as weight, level
from r cross apply (
    select sum(task_weight) from r r2
    where r2.task_chain like r.task_chain + '%'
) as s(cumulative_weight)
order by weight desc;

https://dbfiddle.uk/zdgl3IBA

Thanks. Using cross apply with like condition, may not be a performance issue? I think creating a numeric task code base on ids is better than task chain based on task names.

Also it seems that the order is not ture. why order based on weight? if a sub-task has zero weight the order may be false.

Ok, so I guess you wanted to order by the task names. Funny enough, that's easy to change.

I need this query in MariaDB as well. could you please let me know how to rewrite it without using "cross apply"?

@Mohammad You just change the cross apply to a scalar subquery. https://dbfiddle.uk/kvl_kgxv

Thanks, but if another column like task_price need to be summarized from childeren another subquery should run. is there a way like cross apply to run one subquery for several columns?

If it's critical to avoid the subquery you can always bundle up the returned data and then split it: (https://dbfiddle.uk/nQapcL6G) I'm no expert on MariaDB
